# How to remove escaping slashes from a json inside another json?

Tags: json, gson

I have the following json, that is being populated by:

```
new Gson().toJson(batch.getProducts());
```

But when im adding it to my main JSONObject, the fact that it's a value of a json is doing all the json (even the keys) be escaped.

```
{"name":"Ufud","store":2,"products":"[{\"name\":\"Test2\",\"stock\":2,\"value\":19.9},{\"name\":\"Test2\",\"stock\":2,\"value\":19.9},{\"name\":\"Teste2\",\"stock\":2,\"value\":19.9}]"}
```

Is there any method to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to manipulate your json in future you may consider converting it not into a string, but into a JsonElement which can be quite easily added to already existing JsonObject

```
JsonObject mainObject = getMainObject(); //method which creates your main object. You can change it to variable reference
JsonElement productsElement = new Gson().toJsonTree(batch.getProducts()); //converting your object into JsonElement
mainObject.add("products", productsElement); //insering products element into object.
String json = new Gson().toJson(mainObject); //converting object with products element into a json string
```